# encode string passed to method & add 13

Tags: java, string, loops, encode, rot13

(EDITED)

My problem statement: write a method that will encode the String passed to the method by adding 13 letters to each character in the String. If the letter after adding 13 exceeds 'z' then "wrap around" the alphabet. Then return the encoded String.

```
encodeString("hello") → "uryyb"
encodeString("pie") → "cvr"
encodeString("book") → "obbx"
```

this is what I have so far :

```
public static String encodeString (String input) {

    String output;

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        char c = input.charAt(i);

        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'm') 
            c += 13;
        else if (c >= 'n' && c <= 'z') 
            c -= 13;

        output= (" " + (c));
    }

    return output;
}
```

now I know that I have to create a counter so that the method will continue to loop until it reaches the length of the string passed...and I know that if the charAt(index) is less than the character 'n' that I add 13 and if it is greater then I subtract 13. when I put it all together though I just get so confused and just get a bunch of compiling errors like `Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to String`.

*note* straightforward explanations/answers would be much appreciated...

*****so now my problem is that it keeps telling me my output variable may not have been initialized

Comment: First..You have to put charAt() in your while loop okie dokie?.. else it will read only the first char..

Comment: Google "ROT13" and copy a solution.

Comment: Second. A loop that hits a return with necessity makes no sense. You don't want to return, you want to construct your result string.

Comment: @Ingo how do i do that?

Comment: Third. You have 2 {, but 4 }, this won't work.

Comment: Are you using an IDE? I tidied up the indentation in your code and it suggests that perhaps you think some things are part of loops, when in fact they are not. Use braces for `if` statements to help understand what your control flow is doing.

Comment: You can make a char array of the same length as the input string, then put the changed character at the index position. Finally, you can makle a String from that char array.

Comment: You are overwriting `output` with a new char on every loop, so you won't remember characters you have already computed. You should give an initial value by doing `String output = "";` and then at the end of your loop do something like `output = output + " " + c;` which _concatenates_ the current char onto your `output` string, and then overwrites the variable with the new value. Note that the output line can then be shortened to `output += " " + c;`

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize your `output` variable as an empty String. Furthermore you are always replacing the contents of the `output` variable with the last char you've just encoded. So you have to add every char to the `output` with `+=` instead of `=`.

So here is the fixed solution:

```
public static String encodeString(String input) {
    String output = "";       // initialize as empty String

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        char c = input.charAt(i);

        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'm') {
            c += 13;
        } else if (c >= 'n' && c <= 'z') {
            c -= 13;
        }

        output += " " + c;     // add all chars to the String instead of replacing the whole String with "="!
    }

    return output;
}
```

I beautified your code a bit, so everybody can see what it really does.

Use an IDE!

Answer (score 0):

This code is not the most performatic but works good with Upper and Lower characters.

> hElLo → uRyYb
>
> pIe   → cVr
>
> bOoK  → oBbX

```
private static String encodeString(String string) {
    char[] ret = new char[string.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
        ret[i] = rot13(string.charAt(i));
    }

    return String.valueOf(ret);
}

public static char rot13(char c) {
    if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
        if (Character.compare(Character.toLowerCase(c), 'a') >= 0
                && Character.compare(Character.toLowerCase(c), 'm') <= 0)
            return c += 13;
        else
            return c -= 13;
    }

    return c;
}
```